# Nokia HERE maps SRID

Tags: geodjango, srid, here-maps, nokia

I'm just beginning with GeoDjango and just came across with term SRID.
What I've understood so far is that I'd need to know a little something about the map projection to for example calculate distancese between two locations. Threrefore:
What is the correct Nokia HERE maps SRID? And where to find this information?

Comment: This question can have whole books as answers. Short version: SRID means *Spatial Reference System Identifier*. Which one you should pick depends on what you are planning on using your map for (preserving area/distances, look as you are familiar with, etc.), and not so much in which environment you are programming. For plane coordinate systems, it also depends on where you are, different systems (reference points) are used in different areas of the world to preserve accuracy.

Comment: HERE Maps (formally NOKIA OVI Maps) use "normalized Mercator projection." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20098720/how-do-i-geolocate-an-image-returned-by-the-map-image-api  http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-tile/topics/key-concepts.html

Answer (score 2):

I suspect Nokia HERE is using the same map technique as Google and bing.

So try `EPSG:3857` formerly known as EPSG:900913.